# In solidity how can I add multi dimensional array with struct

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain

In solidity I wonder if I can define an array that can store array of strut inside another array I have gave an example bellow.

```
[ 
  [{id: 1, val: "val1"},{id: 2, val: "val2"},{id: 3, val: "val3"}],  
  [{id: 4, val: "val4"},{id: 5, val: "val5"},{id: 6, val: "val6"}],
]
```

Earlier I had a simple array using which I was just pushing single struct, but in that approach I have to pay gas fee for each array push

So I though if I can make a single list of multiple struct and call push method for that one array then I might be able to save a lot of gas.

I have tried achieving this using the snippet bellow but it doesn't work

```
struct Emp {
uint256 id;
string val;
}

Emp[][] public emprec;

function addEmpArr(Emp[][] memory arr) external {
emprec.push(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something with mappings? `mapping( uint256 => mapping( uint256 => Emp ) ) empRec` or `mapping( uint256 => Emp[]) empRec`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Following your idea i tried to implement the same with mappings. But am not able to figure out how to work with this type of structure. Could you please give me a working example ?

Comment: and while getting this data what will be return type ?   like   `function getEmp() external view returns (empRec memory) {
    return emprec;
  }`